# Unnecessary auto bulk updates occurs on daily basis at specific time are uploading from all subscribers SQL Server merge replication

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, merge-replication

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Merge replication in our environment. the problem is that for almost a month unnecessary auto bulk updates occurs on daily basis at specific time uploading from all subscribers. I have checked everything on my publisher and subscriber for any kind of job or any triggers that can be causing this issue but I'm unable to find any reason.

Comment: Please don't use words such as urgent on this site. We are all volunteers, and the way to encourage people to answer it to write a good question. As it stands there is not enough information to be able to assist.

Comment: Sorry mate, my bad! will keep in mind next time and Thankyou for correcting me